# enable password check for single-user mode

Tags: linux, boot, passwords

I've been trying to find out how to activate that I'm prompted for a password when i boot in single user mode under linux, but I can't find it.

Where can I set this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add an entry to your /etc/inittab

```
su:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin
```

should do it.

This will force sudo, which requires a login password.

Comment: thanks, does that differ between debian-based and rh-based distributions?

Comment: It shouldn't - both use /etc/inittab